# Connecting to Google Api with a proxy server

Tags: java, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

My company's website is using google analytics to track various details, now we have a requirement to fetch all those raw data from google analytics servers and process using out internal tool.

I've created a small Java code using the HelloAnalytics Sample code (Analytics V4 and oAuth 2.0) to fetch session data from google servers. When i am running the same code from my personal computer it's running fine; but when i try to execute the same from company network, it fails throwing either **"Connection Timeout" or "Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?"**.

These issues are obviously due to firewall or the proxy server which is used by my company. I want to know if there's any way to connect to Google Analytics from a corporate network which uses a proxy server.

I've added the **http.proxyHost** and **http.proxyPort** as system property, nothing changed, got the same error.
But when i added **https.proxyHost** and **https.proxyPort** instead of http port, it starting throwing error message *"PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"*

The Google documentations are not helping much :( . Any help is much appreciated.

My Code for reference:

```
  HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
  JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

  //Trying both Explict token and also Client-Serect.json
  GoogleCredential credential2 = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(new TokenResponse().setAccessToken("Some token"));

  GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("client-secret.json")).createScoped(AnalyticsReportingScopes.all());
  AnalyticsReporting service = new AnalyticsReporting.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();      

  GetReportsRequest getReport = //Create the report object to fetch user sessions

  GetReportsResponse response = service.reports().batchGet(getReport).execute();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14262519/1841839  It appears the Google Java client library supports it try Googling after that.    Note: You cant get raw google analytics data out of the API its processed and it is also limited to what you can request out.

Comment: thanks for pointing out in the correct direction. Based on the link i need to get the google certificates and add to the trust store. Where can i find the certificates?
i tried to fetch the cert using "openssl s_client -connect google.com:443" but it kind of crashed throwing error.

Comment: No idea really. I was mostly guessing I did it once a few years ago.  I know its possible I just cant remember how :)