# How to proxy Google API Client requests via WireMock to be able to Record and Play the API responses for unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, proxy, mocking, google-drive-api

I have a class `GoogleApiClientWrapper` which basically handles interactions with Google for authentication and listing files and drives using [Google Drive Java SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java) version: **v3-rev110-1.23.0**.

I am using the following dependencies:

- `google-api-client:1.28.0`
- `google-http-client:1.28.0`
- `google-http-client-apache-2.0.0.jar`
- `com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.32.0`

I am trying to unit test my class. So I thought about using [WireMock Record & Playback](https://wiremock.org/docs/record-playback/) feature to record the requests to Google APIs by routing the requests via WireMock to be able to record the responses for a given request.

So the idea is to create an instance of [HttpTransport](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport.html) which is configured to proxy all requests to localhost on port 8443 which is the port WireMock is running on and inject this `HttpTransport` to the `GoogleRefreshTokenRequest` constructor or the [Drive.Builder](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Builder.html). Then WireMock is configured to proxy requests on localhost to the google api url. So ultimately the requests will be sent to google api the first time then after I am able to record the responses WireMock will be able to respond from the saved mappings.

Here it the implementation of `GoogleRefreshTokenRequest` in `GoogleApiClientWrapper` is as follows:

```
GoogleTokenResponse getGoogleTokenResponse(HttpTransport httpTransport,
                                           JsonFactory jsonFactory,
                                           String refreshToken,
                                           String clientId,
                                           String clientSecret,
                                           List<String> exportScopes) throws IOException {

    return new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest(httpTransport, jsonFactory, refreshToken, clientId, clientSecret)
                    .setScopes(exportScopes)
                    .execute();
}
```

Here is the test class with WireMock code to proxy the request and record the mappings.

```
public class GoogleApiWrapperTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static WireMockClassRule wireMockRule = new WireMockClassRule(WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig().httpsPort(8443));

    @Test
    public void testGetGoogleTokenResponse() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        wireMockRule.startRecording("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token");

        GoogleApiClientWrapper clientWrapper= new GoogleApiClientWrapper();
    
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8443);
        DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
        HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                                   .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
                                   .build();
    
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new ApacheHttpTransport(client);

        String clientId = "my-client-id";
        String clientSecret = "my-client-secret";
        String tokenString = "sometoken";
        String refreshToken =  tokenString.split("\\|")[0];

        GoogleTokenResponse actual = clientWrapper.getGoogleTokenResponse(httpTransport,JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),refreshToken,clientId,clientSecret,Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_READONLY));
        wireMockRule.stopRecording().getStubMappings();
    }
}
```

The following code will be removed from the test class once mapping created:

```
wireMockRule.startRecording("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token");
wireMockRule.stopRecording().getStubMappings();
```

When I run it I get the following exception:

> org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

> Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response

I also tried to create the HttpTransport as follows based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262519/using-proxies-with-google-http-client-library-for-java)

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.0", 8443));
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport.Builder().setProxy(proxy).build();
```

How to solve this issue or is there a missing configuration for the `HttpTransport` or for the WireMockClassRule? Or is there an easier way to be able to store the google api responses via WireMock?

I already used [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) to mock the responses when testing other classes that use the `GoogleApiClientWrapper` class but in this unit test I want to try to test the behaviour.